# How to select the input size of image for CNN visible layer in keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have an images (jpg) data with the following width and height distribution:

[image]

The mean width and height are:

```
print(width.mean());print(height.mean())

1060.6722738386309
1577.478630806846
```

I am confused as to what input i should feed in the visible layer of CNN:

I started with the below configuration:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(400,300,3)))
```

Is the input size i chose reasonable ( I just went with the fact of taking @ 1/3rd mean width and height to start with. Is there some rationale way to select the input_shape?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing it.

1> Fixed input size: In this case you need to resize your image to a fixed size, lets say (400,300,3) using opencv or pillow

or

2> Making Fully convolutional network, just define layer like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(None,None,3)))
```

Comment: My question is, am i reasonable in resizing the images to (400,300,3), which i have done so.

Comment: Ok, ideally, you should try to maintain aspect ratio for the input images. Rest, it depends on the application you are using.

Comment: For example, taking the example of single shot detectors, shape of your each feature map has a great impact on output. So, your input should be ideally a multiple of it in order to cover odd edges & corners. This is generally an observation.

Comment: The images are movie posters scraped from imdb site....just doing a multi-label genre classification exercise.

Comment: You can give it a try using 400,300 , but, make sure to use affine transformations & maintaining aspect ratio while resizing as there is almost 3-4 times compression of original image & size chosen.  Also, give it a try with size 1000 X 600 pixels making smaller side equal to 600 pixels.